# Does Joomla or Drupal integrate better with phpBB forum

Tags: drupal, joomla, integration, phpbb, theming

If it is difficult to integrate or not recommended, I would like to go with Drupal since I am more comfortable with it. But I don't know how difficult it is to customize the look and feel of PHPBB forum to match Drupal website. (I can theme Drupal).

Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

For Joomla! there is [RokBridge](http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokbridge) which does not require code modifications.

RocketThemes also offers matching themes for Joomla!, Drupal and phpBB, but they are not (all) free.

Answer (score 1):

If you can embed the forum in the CMS, check out the Drupal module [phpBBforum](http://drupal.org/project/phpbbforum).

For Joomla there also appears to be an extension, though I haven't worked with this one: [Mehdi's Phpbb THREE bridge](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum-bridges/7829)